# Invalid date | linux sh script

Tags: linux, date, sh

So I have a script which looks for missing "foto's" in a .txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash

inputDateFmt()
{
   sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/\./:/g' <<< "$1"
}
begindatum=$(date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt "2014-10-27_08.01.01")")
einddatum=$(date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt "2014-10-27_18.00.01")")

while [ "$begindatum" != "$einddatum" ]
do
    bestandnaam=$(date --date="$begindatum" +"%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpeg")
    if [ $(grep -Fx "$bestandnaam" fotos.txt) ]
    then
        echo "$bestandnaam found"
    else
       echo  "$bestandnaam not found"
    fi
    begindatum=$(LC_ALL=C date --utc --iso-8601=seconds -d"$begindatum"+1minute)

done
```

But whenever I ran this I got an invalid date as a response.
So i got a comment by someone saying the `begindatum=$(LC_ALL=C date --utc --iso-8601=seconds -d"$begindatum"+1minute)` will never be the same as **$einddatum**.

So I thought to add `einddatum=$(LC_ALL=C date --utc --iso-8601=seconds -d"$einddatum")` under the **$begindatum** variable and this did work in an online bash shell tester but whenever I go back to my VM and use the code I get the error again.

```
    #!/bin/bash

inputDateFmt()
{
   sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/\./:/g' <<< "$1"
}
begindatum=$(date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt "2014-10-27_08.01.01")")
einddatum=$(date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt "2014-10-27_18.00.01")")

while [ "$begindatum" != "$einddatum" ]
do
    bestandnaam=$(date --date="$begindatum" +"%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpeg")
    if [ $(grep -Fx "$bestandnaam" fotos.txt) ]
    then
        echo "$bestandnaam found"
    else
       echo  "$bestandnaam not found"
    fi
    begindatum=$(LC_ALL=C date --utc --iso-8601=seconds -d"$begindatum"+1minute)
    einddatum=$(LC_ALL=C date --utc --iso-8601=seconds -d"$einddatum")

done
```

This is the error:

```
student@debian91:~/Downloads/inzending-project2-voorbeeld$ ./scripttt
date: ongeldige datum: ‘ma okt 27 08:01:01 UTC 2014’
 not found
date: invalid date 'ma okt 27 08:01:01 UTC 2014+1minute'
date: invalid date 'ma okt 27 18:00:01 UTC 2014'
student@debian91:~/Downloads/inzending-project2-voorbeeld$
```

Comment: Don't post the error message as an image. Images can't be copy/pasted or read out on a screen reader.

Comment: `ma okt 27` seem to be swedish or something so! You miss `LANG=C` before `date -u -d "$(inputDateFmt`!

Comment: I believe this is Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

With `LC_ALL=C` your localized date strings cannot be parsed back into machine-readable format.

A better overall approach is to keep dates in machine-readable epoch format (seconds since midnight UTC Jan 1 1970) and convert to human-readable when you need it.

However, if you are genuinely looking for a static sequence of dates, just generate it once, and `grep` once.

```
for hh in {8..18}; do
    hfmt=$(printf '%02i\n' "$hh')
    printf "2014-10-27_$hfmt.%02i.01.jpeg\n" {0..59}
done |
grep -Fxvf - fotos.txt
```

to obtain the missing entries, and similarly without the `-v` flag for the ones which are not missing.

Comment: While I do understand what u mean, with just removing it the error code stays the same, and i tried some other things by changing it into seconds which still gives me an error.

Comment: See update now. I hope I am guessing your intention correctly.